# Given a open set U containing a point z in the complex plane. Check that there exists a point w in U such that |w| > |z|.

Tags: complex-analysis

I **need this** to prove the **maximum modulus principle**.
If f is a non-c0nstant analytic function on a connected open set U and z$\in$U. By open mapping theorem, we know that f(U) is an open set containing f(z). Thus, we use the above statement to conclude that, there exists a **w $\in$ f(U) such that |w| > |f(z)|**. Thus for some $u\in U$ we have w = f(u). Hence |f| does not have a maximum at any point of U.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpret $~|z|~$ as the (non-negative) length of the line segment from $~0~$ to $~z.~$

Since $~U~$ is open, $~z~$ is an interior point, which implies that there exists $~r > 0,~$ such that the circle of radius $~r~$ centered at $~z~$ is completely in $~U.~$

Draw the line segment from $~0~$ thru $~z~$ and extend it until it crosses the circle at two points.  One of those two points must be further away from $~0~$ than $~z~$ is.

**Edit**
As suggested in the comment by Robert Israel, the case of $~z = 0~$ yields to the similar result that that there exists $~r > 0,~$ such that the circle of radius $~r~$ centered at $~(z = 0)~$ is in $~U.~$

Comment: Of course you have to also consider the (easy) case $z=0$.